# Error:(246, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''

Tags: android

I've tried all the techniques which were provided on stack overflow but I am still getting the same error. Even after modifying the name, when I am try rebuilding the gradle, again the same is being updated to the previous value and the error is being arose.

The error is :

```
Error:(246, 5) error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/font' with config ''
```

Comment: did you try to clean the project or invalidate cache of the AS ?

Comment: No sir I've not tried that..

Comment: Yes sir, I tried but getting the same error